# Full screen modal Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, liferay-theme

I am using my web Bootstrap 3. I put some pictures with Bootstrap modal option I want to be expanded to full screen. As I can get it ??

I want the image is enlarged as much as possible the whole screen and obviously not lose responsive on devices

This is the best thing known to do.

CODE: [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/NZZPP83A73)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In html:

```
<div class="modal-content modal-fullscreen">
```

In css:

```
.modal-fullscreen{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```